# How to open a Chrome application into Robot using selenium2Library

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to open our windows Chrome exe in Robot using selenium2Library. I've tried creating a webdriver using Create Webdriver with this code but it's not working.

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()       sys, selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
${options.add_extension}=        Set_Variable          path/to/extension
Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
```

In Python I do this... and it launches my app in selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def chromedr():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/InTouch Health/Carestation/Carestation.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/InTouch Health/Carestation/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)  
    return driver
```

How can I do this in Robot/selenium2Library?

I was able to launch the Application using this code:
${options}= Evaluate sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions() sys, selenium.webdriver Create WebDriver Chrome my_alias chrome_options=${options} executable_path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Myapp.exe

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get any errors? Does it open the wrong browser? Does robot crash?

Comment: I was able to launch my app with ...    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    my_alias    chrome_options=${options}    executable_path=C:/Program Files (x86)/InTouch Health/Carestation/Carestation.exe
But, I'm unable to use that webdriver instance with other calls like close Browser. How can I make a unique webdrive(link to an app) and have my selenium/robot calls directed to it. Is there a way to pass this object to the other calls or make it a global object?

Comment: Note with python/ selenium I use 'driver' in the example above.

Comment: please don't put code in the comment section, it's impossible to read. If you need to add more information to your question, you can [edit] your question. And you haven't answered my first question, which is "what does 'not working' mean?

Comment: By not working - it was always launching the Chrome Browser not my Chomium application. I want to launch a chromium application. I was now able to do this but now I can't seem to use the Chomium app object with the rest of the robot/selenium2library calls. How can this work?

Comment: You are setting the `binary_location` attribute in the python code, have you tried doing that in your robot code?

Comment: I did try adding it as Call Method | ${options} | add_argument | binary_location\="path to .exe" But this didn't work. It would just open the chrome browser not my app.

Answer (score -1):

To open chrome with robotframework selenium2library

1) install selenium2Library  through pip

2) download and extract Chrome driver exe, add it to environment variables

3) you can invoke chrome like below

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
*** Variables ***
${SiteUrl}    https://stackoverflow.com
${Browser}    Chrome
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Open Browser and login
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser and login
    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}
```

Comment: The OP does not want to open chrome. They want to open a chromium application, which is different. It's based on chrome, but it's not the chrome webbrowser.